# Unity Calling Function with a Animation From Another Script

Tags: c#, unityscript

Could someone please help me with this problem I have spent all night trying to solve.
I have looked at a lot of forums and videos on how to access a function from another script and the only answers I get are ones that show me how to receive a print statement or a number value from another script. 
I am trying to get my 2 scripts to communicate, where if my `Health <= 0` then call my function from my script which should make my char animate death. Here is my script. This is a 2D game as well.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Collision : MonoBehaviour

{

Animator anim;

 public isDead die;

    public int PlayerHealth = 100;
    void Start()
    {
        // I did this to test if it was working so I didn't have to wait for the health to drop
        die.Death();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D Coll)
    {

        if (Coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {

            PlayerHealth -= 10;
        }

        if (PlayerHealth <= 0)
        {
            die.Death();

        }

    }

}
```

---

Here is my other script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class isDead : MonoBehaviour

{

    Animator Anim;

    int IsDead = Animator.StringToHash("IsDead");

    void Start()
    {
        Death();
    }

    public void Death()
    {
        Anim.SetTrigger(IsDead);       
    }
}
```

Could someone please help me? Thanks!

---

Here's what I did to fix it thanks to your help

First I did not associate my isDead Die to an object so I associated it with my Hero (player) object that had the animator in it. Then I was missing this in my script for isDead function Death()

Anim = GetComponent (); (Animator) wont show in its <> but that is what I put in the brackets.

so by adding that to my Death() function, and associating that first script to my gameobject within unity I was able to animate on collision using two different scripts.

Comment: I assume you have attached both scripts to game objects, and specified the "public isDead die" property in the Unity inspector to point to an object that has the "isDead" script attached to it. Try putting a print("death happened"); in the Death() method before starting the animation, to see if it gets called. Check if the Anim is null. Provide details about what happened, is there an error message?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't name your class "Collision". There is already a built-in class named Collision in Unity.

Comment: Yes there is an error code, its NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Thanks you for the tips as well Ill work on changing that script name

Comment: I have my isDead script attached to my GameObject that has my Animator in it, and I have my Collision script to the GameObject above it in the Hierarchy that has my box collider2d on it.

Comment: Okay wow your awesome thank you so much. I have solved the problem. This is my first time using a forum like this for help with coding, and I will definitely try this again next time I have a huge brain fart like last night.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Next time look at the error, you can double click error messages in the Unity output and it will show you where the nullreference is. When you can't find out what's wrong and you want to try asking for help, post the exact error too. Also, http://answers.unity3d.com/ is probably a better place than stackoverflow for Unity-specific issues.